# Display a Pardot Custom Field on Thank You (Code) page of Form

Tags: javascript, java, form, pardot

I have a Pardot form where the person enters an Account# (field is populated already in Pardot). They hit submit, and I'd like the Thank You text in Pardot to display another field of their's based on their Account#. It seems like you can do it with a little JavaScript but haven't found an example close to my use case yet.

I thought I could just reference the field, but that doesn't work.

Thank you for submitting, your Gold ID is: `%%gold_ID_#%%`.

This works if I use a field in the form, but this is not in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Pardot Dynamic Content, then insert the provided embed code (javascript) onto your website (can be any website).

Insert Pardot field variables within the Dynamic Content and they will render with prospect data from Pardot.

Of course you'll need a Pardot plan that has Dynamic Content feature.